# Phonegap iOS app loads in portrait orientation when the device is in landscape orientation

Tags: cordova, ios7, screen-orientation

I've written an iOS phonegap (phonegap 3.1) app that has tuned out relatively well. There is however an issue when the device (an iPad air, iOS 7) is in landscape orientation when the app loads. The splash screen renders in landscape but the view of the app is in portrait orientation. What is also strange is that when I flip the device to portrait orientation the view port becomes more narrow. The app works as expected when launched in portrait orientation.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this issue?

**Update**
For anyone who comes across this, I over came this issue by building a new version of the app using phonegap 3.2

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with phonegap version i am using 2.1.0 but still me too have overcome this issue.

Comment: In my case issue was from my own code.

Comment: I was using the Status bar plugin which could have had something to do with my issue. In PG 3.1 I couldn't figure out how to hide the status bar without the plugin, where as in 3.2 I was able to hide it without using the status bar plugin.

Comment: Exactly me too was using a PG plugin to solve the status bas issue.. I was hardcoding the bounds of my view. So it was taking the same bounds in landscape also.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue on cordova 3.1 and also solved it by upgrading cordova, but to version 3.3.0 (I skipped 3.2 and didn't try that version).

Since I can't post comments, how did you remove the status bar without using the plugin?

Comment: In the .plist I set "Status bar is initially hidden" to yes and "View controller-based status bar appearance" to no, and that seemed to do the trick. You may have to add these values if they aren't already in the plist file